# Exporting from org-mode to markdown

Tags: org-mode

The emacs functions mentioned in the docs don't seem to exist in my org version 7.9.3f.

http://orgmode.org/manual/Markdown-export.html

Any idea how I can get org-mode to export to markdown for me without pulling my hair out?

Comment: I have version 8.2.10 of org-mode, installed from melpa, and these two functions are available for me.

Comment: yeah I guess I pulled 8.1.x from ELPA and they don't exist... bah

Comment: Check this out and take a look inside org-mode? I'm guessing you won't have the `ox-md.el` file but who knows. http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/ox-overview.html

Comment: Is upgrading Org Mode a valid option? Or should this be read as "How can I add Markdown export support to Org 7.9.3f?".

Comment: Markdown was not appearing for me as an option in the Org Export Dispatcher until I ran `M-x org-md-export-to-markdown`. After that it appeared every time afterwards, including after restarts.

Comment: @Conor 's comment should be an answer, and accepted.

Comment: Put this into your `init.el`: `(require 'ox-md)
(add-to-list 'org-export-backends 'markdown)
`

Answer (score 37):

You should customize `org-export-backends` and enable the markdown backend.

`M-x customize-option` and then `org-export-backends` and then arrow down to the checkbox to the left of 'md' and press enter to enable it (or just click on it, if running emacs graphically). Then arrow back up and over to 'Apply and Save' (or click on it).

After customizing, run `M-x org-md-export-to-markdown`. Now you should have a new markdown file in the same directory which is an export of the original org mode file.

Comment: That's: `M-x customize-option` and then `org-export-backends` and then arrow down to the checkbox to the left of 'md' and press enter to enable it (or just click on it, if running emacs graphically). Then arrow back up and over to 'Apply and Save' (or click on it).

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this package:

https://github.com/larstvei/ox-gfm

If you want specifically Github-Flavored Markdown, that should help.

Answer (score 8):

It can be done using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/):

```
pandoc -s progress.org -o progress.md
```

or if you have a lot of files to convert:

```
mkdir md
for f in *.org; do pandoc "$f" -s -o "md/${f%.org}.md"; done
```

Comment: How about a link to info about pandoc?

Comment: I didn't feel it's worth the time / effort to find the url and copy and paste the link. But I welcome anyone to edit my answer with this information.

Answer (score 4):

The two functions mentioned in the [Link](http://orgmode.org/manual/Markdown-export.html) you mentioned, as of Org-mode version 8.0, are part of the `ox-md.el` that has become part of the [New Exporter Framework](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/ox-overview.html).

For upgrade instructions and more information take a look at the [Upgrade Guide](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-8.0.html#sec-6-1) and also the [announcement](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/65574) of this new framework by its author Nicolas Goaziou.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(require 'ox-md nil t))
```

as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22990257/6277148)? Once loaded you should see the export option in the normal org export list.

Comment: The answers indicated he needed to enable the backends. As an aside using ox-gfm, I needed this: (use-package ox-gfm
  :defer 3
  :after org)